# Devolver el n-ésimo número de la serie Fibonacci con JavaScript

Tags: javascript, funciones, while, fibonacci

Necesito crear una función que recibe un numero `n` y devuelve devuelve el `n`-ésimo número de la serie Fibonacci.

Por ejemplo, si pasamos `num = 3` debería devolver `1` (Fibonacci: 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, etc.)

Pude conseguir que por consola imprima los números de la serie, pero no que me devuelva el `n` solicitado.

Vale aclarar que para la solución solo puedo aplicar if/else, while/for y obviamente funciones.

Comparto hasta donde llegue con mi código:

```
function fibonacci(num) {
  let a = 0;
  let b = 1;
  let c;

  for(let i = 1; i < num; i++) {
    c = a + b;
    console.log(a);
    console.log(b);
    console.log(c);
    a = b + c;
    b = c + a;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No te devuelve nada porque no pusiste el return, tambien te recomiendo inicializar la variable c, algo que deberias de checar es que no estas calculando el valor bien

```
function fibonacci(num){
 let a=0
 let b=1
 let c = 0
 for(let i=1;i<num;i++){
   c=a+b
   console.log(a);
   console.log(b);
   console.log(c);
   a=b+c
   b=c+a
 }
 return c
}
```

Mi recomendación es hacer esto:

```
 function fibonacci(num){
 let a = 0;
 let b = 1;
 let c = 0;
 if(num === 1){
   return 1;
 }
 for(let i = 0; i < num - 1; i++){
   c = a + b;
   a = b;
   b = c;
 }
 return c;
}

for(let i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
  console.log(fibonacci(i));
}
```

Saludos

Comment: Hay un detalle que pasaste por alto. Si quiere calcular el `n esimo` valor, la variable `i` debería estar inicializada a 0 y no a 1, puesto que con ese bucle for calcularás el `n-1 esimo`.

Comment: Tienes razón no había tomado eso en cuenta.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tomarse el tiempo de ayudar! Me sirvio la respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Te propongo una solución alternativa:

```
let a = 0;
let b = 1;
let c = 0;
let num = 10;
var fibb = [0, 1];

for(let i = 0; i < num; i++)
{
   c = a + b
   fibb.push(c);
   a = b ;
   b = c;
}

console.log(fibb[x]);//Accedemos a cualquier posición del arreglo
```

Creamos el **arreglo fibb**, al cual le iremos añadiendo, cada elemento calculado de la **secuencia de Fibbonacci**, al guardar estos elementos en un arreglo podremos calcular la cantidad de elementos de la secuencia que deseemos, y acceder al elemento que queramos posteriormente mediante:

```
console.log(fibb[x]);
```

Donde **x** representa cualquier posición del arreglo.

Comment: Cito al autor en la pregunta -> *Vale aclarar que para la solución solo puedo aplicar if/else, while/for y obviamente funciones.* Si bien el código parece correcto, parece ser que los array no pueden formar parte de la solución.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta!

Answer (score 0):

Comparto la solución encontrada:

```
function fibonacci(num) {
  let a = 1;
  let b = -1;
  let count;
  while (num >= 0) {
    count = a;
    a = a + b;
    b = count;
    num--;
  }
  return b;
}
```