# Fibonacci con javascript

Tags: javascript

> Programa que calcule el valor de la sucesión de Fibonacci a
> partir de la posición x.

```
    for (var i = 0; i <= posicion; i++) {
      var contador = i + contador;
    }
    alert("La posición " + posicion + " es " + contador);
  }
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es el error que tienes? ¿No sería mejor "encapsular" el funcionamiento en una función? Puedes revisar [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/440066/devolver-el-n-%c3%a9simo-n%c3%bamero-de-la-serie-fibonacci-con-javascript) para revises el algoritmo.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Devolver el n-ésimo número de la serie Fibonacci con JavaScript](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/440066/devolver-el-n-%c3%a9simo-n%c3%bamero-de-la-serie-fibonacci-con-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para calcular cualquier número de la **serie Fibonacci** puedes usar la **razón de oro** o **razón áurea**. Este número áureo tiene un valor aproximado de **1.618**, para aprender más sobre él puedes consultar la **Wikipedia**:
https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/N%C3%BAmero_%C3%A1ureo

La fórmula para calcular cualquier número de la **serie Fibonacci** es:

```
X(n) = (φ^n − (1−φ)^n) / √5
```

Para calcular la posición **7** de la serie haríamos lo siguiente:

```
X(7) = ((1,618)^7 − (1−1,618)^7) / √5
```

Traducido a **Javascript** quedaría como:

```
var phi = 1.618;
var raiz5 = Math.sqrt(5);
var Xn = (Math.pow(phi, 7) - Math.pow((1 - phi), 7)) / raiz5;

Xn = Math.round(Xn);
print(Xn);
```

Aquí declaramos la **variable phi** cuyo valor será el **numero áureo**, declaramos la variable **raiz5** que hará el cálculo de la **raíz cuadrada de 5**. Posteriormente hacemos el cálculo correspondiente empleando la fórmula antes descrita y redondeamos para obtener un valor entero, finalmente imprimimos el resultado obtenido.

**Nota1:** Aquí hacemos el cálculo para la posición **7** de la **serie de Fibonacci** cuyo valor es 13, para calcular otras números de la serie debes poner la posición correspondiente.

**Nota2:** Mientras más decimales le añadas al número áureo más exacto será el resultado.